# SageMaker Distributed Training in Local Mode (inside Notebook Instances)

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I've been using SageMaker for a while and have performed several experiments already with distributed training. I am wondering if it is possible to test and run SageMaker distributed training in local mode (using SageMaker Notebook Instances)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, not possible yet. [local mode](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#local-mode) does not support the distributed training with `local_gpu`for Gzip compression, Pipe Mode, or manifest files for inputs

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SageMaker supports distributed training in local mode. But as @Philipp Schmid said some other features (like pipemode are not supported).